# Does modifying robots.txt take effect immediately?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

I am trying to solve an issue where Googlebot seems to be eating up my CPU usage. To confirm my guess, I modify robots.txt on my website's root folder, adding

```
Disallow: /
```

to it. I have two websites on different servers both of them are having this issue. So for one of them, after I edited robots.txt the CPU usage drops to a normal level, for the other I see from apache access log that the Googlebot is still coming in.

So I go to Google search console to test robots.txt. For the first one I see that google already discovered the latest robots.txt and stop crawling my website; For the second one google is still using an old version of robots.txt. So modifying robots.txt doesn't always take effect immediately, am I right? And if so, how do I notify google that I have a new robots.txt?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this to disallow all user agents though:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

For the search engine re-indexing, it might take between a few days to four weeks before Googlebots index a new site ([reference](https://www.boostability.com/how-often-is-google-crawling-my-site/)).